# How to add a dropdown to CK Editor with a list of class names

Tags: ckeditor, sonata

How to add a dropdown to CK Editor with a list of class names that I can then assign to text? 
I need to add some classes for images too and I believe the definition needs to be set for each tag type.
I've studied the docs and there's examples for inline styling but I need classes.

In fact this is for CK Editor used within Sonata CMS, but it must be the same structure.

Weird that it's not there - TinyMce can do it easily.

Answer (score 0):

As a much longer thread advises:

```
allowedContent: true
```

if there are other directives in that, get rid of them - this also bypasses the context sensitive blocking

Then - note this is for Sonata with a config in the yaml

`stylesSet:
     - { name: 'My class', element: 'div', attributes: { class: 'myclass' }}
     - { name: 'Icon', element: 'img', attributes: { class: 'myicon' }}`

Why is it not clearly documented at CK Editor?